# jQuery generate random number at a random time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a plugin.  In this plugin, I have two variables; rateMin and rateMax.  I would like to generate a random number between these two numbers and use it as a setInterval time. Then once that number is used, make another random number and use that.

Here's a quick example:

```
var defaults = {
    rateMin: 500,
    rateMax: 2000
}

var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
return this.each(function(defaults){

var rate = Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.rateMax - options.rateMin + 1)) + options.rateMin; // MAKE A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN MAX AND MIN
setInterval(function(){
    var rate = Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.rateMax - options.rateMin + 1)) + options.rateMin
    //DO SOMETHING
}, rate);
```

I was hoping by doing it this way that the rate would override itself with a new number and be used on the next time the setInterval is called.  But it is still using only the first number made before the setInterval.

I guess I don't know how to use a variable outside of it's function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You would need to stop the old interval and start a new one every time the delay changes. with that in mind, you mightaswell use setTimeout.

Comment: The var keyword makes a new variable inside the scope of the interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) instead of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) if you don't want the delay to be the same each time. Also, don't use `var rate` in the callback if you want it to overwrite the variable in the outer scope. That said, I'd just encapsulate that piece of logic in a function and forget about it.

```
function getNextRate() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.rateMax - options.rateMin + 1)) + options.rateMin;
}

setTimeout(function foo(){
    //DO SOMETHING

    setTimeout(foo, getNextRate());
}, getNextRate());
```

Comment: Will this be able to do the action again and again?  This is supposed to be an infinite loop

Comment: @ntgCleaner yes. You need to explicitly call `setTimeout` in the callback. See my edit.

Comment: Great example.  This is precisely what I was looking for.  Thank you!